# Find all continuous real valued function such that $(f(x))^2+C=\int\limits_0^xf(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Find all continuous real valued function such that $$(f(x))^2+C=\int\limits_0^xf(t)dt$$
>   for some $C\in\mathbb{R}$

If I set $F(x)=\int\limits_0^xf(t)dt$ then $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x)$,

so $(f(x))^2+C$ is diferentible as it does $\sqrt{F(x)-C}=|f(x)|$,

and then $F'(x)=(|f(x)|^2+C)'=2|f(x)||f(x)|'=f(x)$.

and then I don't know how to continue. I just see the solution $f(x)=0$ whith $C=0$.

Comment: not for "some" $C$

Comment: $F'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)=f(x)$ so either $f(x)=0$ or $2f'(x)=1$ when $f(x)\ne 0$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135029/find-all-continuous-functions-satisfying-int-0xf-fx2c-for-some-constan?rq=1 This question seems to have been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose $f$ is differentiable. differentiating $$ (f(x))^2+C=\int\limits_0^xf(t)dt \tag 1$$ gives us $$2ff' = f \to f' = \frac12, f = \frac12x + k$$ puuting it back in $(1)$ we get $$\left(\frac12x + k\right)^2 + C= \frac14 x^2 + kx $$ putting $x = 0$ connect $$ C = -k^2, \quad f = \frac12x+k.$$

Comment: That's true, maybe try to find all of them (i.e. the ones that are not diferentiable everywhere) is more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

You have on differentiating both sides, $2f(x)f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$. Choose some $x$ for which $f(x)\neq0$ then $2f'(x)=1\implies f(x)=\dfrac{x}{2}+K$ where K is another constant.

Note that $f(0)=K$ in our solution. In your given equation, setting $x=0$, we have $f(0)^2+C=0\implies K^2+C=0\implies K=\sqrt{-C}$

Note that $C\leq0$ so that it makes sense. Hence $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{2}+\sqrt{-C}$

Comment: Is $f(x)=0$ also a solution?

Comment: There is also the constant zero solution, which is ruled out by the division procedure you used at the start.

Comment: That depends on how you define your $C$. $f$ can be $0$ if $C=0$

Comment: Well, $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, so $f=0$ has a $C \in \mathbb{R}$ where the equation holds....

Comment: No, your $C$ is fixed and true for all $x$. You are NOT varying your $C$. If you did then your $C$ would become a function of $x$ and thus you would be having two functions $f$ and $C$ and the problem would become practically unsolvable.

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is differentiable?