# Find all continuous function satisfying $\int_0^xf(x)=(f(x))^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Find all continuous function satisfying $\int_0^xf(t)dt=(f(x))^2$.

$f(x)$ is differentiable at $f(x) \not=0$ since $\sqrt{(f(x)^2}$ is differentiable at $f(x)^2 \not=0$ by the chain rule.

Then, $f(x) = 2 f(x) f^\prime(x)$ by FTC. And, since $f(x) \not = 0, f^\prime(x) = 1/2$.  Then, $f(x) = x/2 + c$ for some constant $c$.

Let $x = 0$. Then, we have $f(0) = c$. Sub $f(0)$ into the equation in the question. We have $0 = (c)^2$. Therefore, $c = 0$ (i.e. $f(x) = x/2)$.

But, I don't understand the following solution:

$$f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac {x-a}{2} &\quad\text{if} \hspace{0.2cm} x<a\\
       0 &\quad\text{if} \hspace{0.2cm} a\le x \le b \\
       \frac{x-b}{2} &\quad\text{if} \hspace{0.2cm} x>b\\
     \end{cases}$$
where $a \le 0$ and $b \ge 0$ are two real numbers.

I found one [explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135029/find-all-continuous-functions-satisfying-int-0xf-fx2c-for-some-constan) regarding this solution. But, I have difficulty in understanding some terminology like maximal interval in the explanation. So, could you explain why should we consider the interval, and how can we derive this solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt = (f(x))^2$?  And how do you justify "since $f(x)\ne0$" when the zero function is an obvious solution?

Comment: Yes. $\int_0^x f(t)dt = (f(x))^2$. I edited it.

Comment: Then, I cannot use $\sqrt {f(x)^2}$ to justify the differentiability of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

As $f$ is continuous, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that $F(x):=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is differenttiable and that $$F'(x)=f(x).$$

Assume that for some $x$, we have $f(x)\ne 0$.
Then from $F(x)=f(x)^2$, we get
$$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)^2-f(x)^2}{h(f(x)+f(x+h))}\\&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h(f(x)+f(x+h))}\\&=\frac{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}}{f(x)+\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h)}\\&=\frac{F'(x)}{2f(x)}\\&=\frac{f(x)}{2f(x)}\\&=\frac12,\end{align}$$
i.e., $f$ is differentiable with $f'(x)=\frac12$ wherever $f(x)\ne 0$.
Note that we cannot make a statement about the differentiability of $f$ at points where $f(x)=0$!

I made the limit calculation above explicite to show where $f(x)\ne 0$ enters the argument. 
You *can* do the same with the chain rule $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sqrt{F(x)}=\frac{F'(x)}{2\sqrt{F(x)}}=\frac{f(x)}{2f(x)}=\frac12$$
which is also applicable *only* where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is differentiable, i.e., only when $F(x)>0$.

Assume there exists $x_0$ with $f(x_0)>0$. Let $u=\sup\{\,x<x_0\mid f(x)\le 0\,\}$ amd $v=\inf\{\,x>x_0\mid f(x)\le 0\,\}$ (with the possibility that $u=-\infty$ and/or $v=+\infty$). Then $f$ is differentiable with $f'(x)=\frac12$ on the open interval $(u,v)$ and we conclude that $f(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{x-x_0}2$ there. 
If $u=-\infty$, we find that $f(x_0-2f(x_0))=0$, contradicting the definition of $u$. Hence $u\in\Bbb R$ and by continuity we have both $f(u)=f(x_0)-\frac{u-x_0}2$ and $f(u)=0$. We conclude that $u=x_0-2f(x_0)$.
If $v<\infty$, we similarly obtain $0=f(v)=f(x_0)+\frac{v-x_0}2$, hence $v=x_0-2f(x_0)<x_0$, which is absurd. We conclude $v=\infty$.
Thus

> If $f(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0$, then $f(x)=\frac{x-b}2$ for all $x\ge b$ with $b:=x_0-2f(x_0)$.

By a symmetric argument

> If $f(x_0)<0$ for some $x_0$, then $f(x)=\frac{x-a}2$ for all $x\le a$ with $a:=x_0-2f(x_0)$.

Clearly, if both signs occur as values, we must have $a\le b$ in the above.
Depending on whether or not $f$ assumes positive and/or negative values, we obtain the following complete lst of solutions:

$$ f(x)=0$$
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x-b}2,&x\ge b\\0,&x\le b\end{cases}\qquad\text{for some }b\in\Bbb R$$
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x-a}2,&x\le a\\0,&x\ge a\end{cases}\qquad\text{for some }a\in\Bbb R$$
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x-a}2,&x\le a\\0,&a\le x\le b\\
\frac{x-b}2,&x\ge b
\end{cases}\qquad\text{for some }a,b\in\Bbb R\text{ with }a\le b$$
We can summarize the first three cases under the last if we allow $a=-\infty$ and/or $b=+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. But, I still don't understand some part of your explanation. After you define $u$ and $v$, then says $f$ is differentiable on $(u,v).$ Why the interval should be $(u,v)$?  And, how can we conclude that $f(x) = f(x_0)+\frac{x-x_0}{2}$?