# Find all continous functon satisfying: $\int_{0}^{x} f = f^2(x) + C$, for some constant $C$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Find all continous function satisfying: $\int_{0}^{x} f = f^2(x) + C$, for some constant $C$
This is problem 7 of Chapter 14, Calculus by Spivak.

My approach involves differentiating both sides of the equation. But by doing so, we assume the differentiability of  $f$ in $R$. It's impossible to think of something else other than considering derivatives. So let we say: $f$ is a **differentiable function** for simplicity.

So we have:

$$\int_{0}^{x}f = f^2(x) +C \Leftrightarrow f(x) = 2f(x)f'(x) \Leftrightarrow 
\left[
 \begin{array}{rcr}
    f(x) =0 \\
    f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} \\
  \end{array}(**)
\right.$$

There are two cases to consider: either $f(x)$ is $0$ for every x in R **or** there exists some $x$ satisfying $f(x) \not= 0$

So, $f(x) =0,\forall x\in R$ is one solution. The other solutions are $f$(s) such that: $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$, for $x$ such that $f(x) \not= 0 $

It seems that there's no guarantee that the set $\{x: f(x) \not= 0\}$ can be any specific set. If we assume $f(x) = 0$ only once at $0$ then $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ is another solution. But is that all in the second case?
I'm trying to somehow exclude other cases. I haven't found any promising approach yet. Any ideas ?

Comment: Repeated question, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135029/find-all-continuous-functions-satisfying-int-0xf-fx2c-for-some-constan?rq=1).

Comment: You need to consider any open interval on which $f$ is nonzero and use the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous. I think the linked question/solution are far more involved than necessary, but I haven't looked carefully.